# why my cont.style line is not working in this function

Tags: javascript, css

Why is my cont.style line not working under each if condition?

I am using to update my bars height in the code where this function is called, but the main line of cont.style is not working which is written under each if condition rather the one written under else condition is working very smoothly.

I think the fault is with the if condition or the parameters passed to the update function. I have also tried passing array_size in parameters but still same error is there. If condtion is used for mobile view and under each nested if the array size is reduced so that it will be clear for the people to see the bars easily in the mobile view as well.

```js
function update(cont, height, color) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)").matches) {
      if (array_size > 20 && array_size < 30) {
        array_size = array_size % 10;
        cont.style = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) + "%; 
        height: " + (height) + " % ;
        background: " + color + ";
        ";
      }
      if (array_size > 30 && array_size < 40) {
        array_size = array_size % 10 + 10;
        cont.style = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) +
          "%; height:" + (height) + "%; background:" + color + ";";
      }
      if (array_size > 40 && array_size < 50) {
        array_size = array_size % 10 + 15;
        cont.style = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) +
          "%; height:" + (height) + "%; background:" + color + ";";
      }
      if (array_size == 30 || array_size == 40 || array_size == 50) {
        array_size = array_size % 10 + 12;
        cont.style = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) +
          "%; height:" + (height) + "%; background:" + color + ";";
      }

    } else {
      cont.style = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) +
        "%; height:" + (height) + "%; background:" + color + ";";
    }
  }, delay += delay_time);
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it to provide a [mcve] - we have no idea what a `cont` is

Comment: It is because `cont.style` is a object, not a string. you should do something like, `cont.style.margin = margin_size + "%"`

Comment: _"is not working"_ is the most useless statement. It doesn't tell us anything about your actual problem. Is there an error? Is the resulting style not correct? Is the generated string not correct? is the function not executed? ...

Comment: @TechySharnav Or `.cssText = ...`

Comment: @Vikash Please try provide whole code(code snippet with html,css,js) it will give better insight of problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change cont.style to cont.style.property

```
   if (array_size > 20 && array_size < 30) {
            array_size = array_size % 10;
            cont.style.margin = margin_size + "%";
            cont.style.width= (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size))+"%"; 
            cont.style.height= height+"%" ;
            cont.style.background= color;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you are trying to do, you might be looking for `cssText`.

```js
function update(cont, height, color) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)").matches) {
      if (array_size > 20 && array_size < 30) {
        array_size = array_size % 10;
        cont.style.cssText = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) + "%; 
        height: " + (height) + " % ;
        background: " + color + ";
        ";
      }
      if (array_size > 30 && array_size < 40) {
        array_size = array_size % 10 + 10;
        cont.style.cssText = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) +
          "%; height:" + (height) + "%; background:" + color + ";";
      }
      if (array_size > 40 && array_size < 50) {
        array_size = array_size % 10 + 15;
        cont.style.cssText = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) +
          "%; height:" + (height) + "%; background:" + color + ";";
      }
      if (array_size == 30 || array_size == 40 || array_size == 50) {
        array_size = array_size % 10 + 12;
        cont.style.cssText = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) +
          "%; height:" + (height) + "%; background:" + color + ";";
      }

    } else {
      cont.style.cssText = " margin: " + margin_size + "%; width:" + (100 / array_size - (2 * margin_size)) +
        "%; height:" + (height) + "%; background:" + color + ";";
    }
  }, delay += delay_time);
}
```